# Computing $\cos^4 20^{\circ}+\cos^4 40^{\circ}+\cos^4 60^{\circ}+\cos^4 80^{\circ}$

Tags: trigonometry

Compute $$\cos^4 20^{\circ}+\cos^4 40^{\circ}+\cos^4 60^{\circ}+\cos^4 80^{\circ}$$

Suppose that this is a scenario where calculator isn't allowed.
I want to say that this expression has something to do with this equation $\cos^2 20^{\circ}+\cos^2 40^{\circ}+\cos^2 60^{\circ}+\cos^2 80^{\circ}=\frac 74$ but I can't seem to find a method to solve this without relying on brute forcing every term to $\cos20^{\circ}$

Comment: I didn't actually brute force every term to $\cos20$ (for this problem, way too tedious), but I had solved one problem that is rather similar. $\cos20-\cos40+\cos60-\cos80=\frac 12$ which I used brute force. Later I did find a simpler solution by using sum-to-product identity to show that $\cos20-\cos80=\cos40$

Comment: Are you, by any chance, using degrees instead of radians?

Comment: Yes, in degrees

Answer (score 3):

We can use the "inverse" rule : just like how we compute $\cos n \theta$ from powers of $\cos \theta$, we may compute powers of $\cos \theta$ using values of $\cos n\theta$, which is what we should desire here, since the sequence $20n$ has some regularity(remainder on division by $90$, values for which we know $\sin \backslash\cos$ like $60,120$ etc.) which we can exploit.

Indeed, we have the following situation : $2\cos^2 \theta  = \cos 2 \theta - 1$, so squaring and using the $\cos 2\theta$ formula again gives:
$$
\cos^4 \theta = \frac{3 + 4\cos 2 \theta + \cos 4 \theta}{8}
$$

Let's use this formula:
$$
8\cos^4 20  = 3 + 4 \cos 40 + \cos 80 \\
8 \cos^4 40 = 3 + 4 \cos 80 + \cos 160 \\
8 \cos^4 80 = 3 + 4 \cos 160 + \cos 320 
$$

Note that $\cos 40 + \cos 80 + \cos 160 = 0$, and $\cos 80 + \cos 160 + \cos 320 = 0$
! These can be checked by combining two of the three angles into the sum of cosines type formula.

Hence, adding all the above gives $\cos^4 20 + \cos^4 40 + \cos^4 80 = \frac 9{8}$. Adding $\cos^4 60 = \frac 1{16}$ gives the answer $\frac{19}{16}$.

Moral : the inverse formulas are really helpful in problems involving multiples of numbers with "regularity" as I described above.

Answer (score 1):

From [Upon multiplying $\cos(20^\circ)\cos(40^\circ)\cos(80^\circ)$ by the sine of a certain angle, it gets reduced. What is that angle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/616033/upon-multiplying-cos20-circ-cos40-circ-cos80-circ-by-the-sine-of-a-c/616079#616079),

$$t_1=\cos20^\circ,t_2=-\cos40^\circ,t_3=-\cos80^\circ$$ are the roots of $$8t^3-6t-1=0$$

$$\implies t_1+t_2+t_3=0,t_1t_2+t_2t_3+t_3t_1=-\dfrac68,t_1t_2t_3=\dfrac18$$ and $8t^4=6t^2+t$

$$\implies8(t_1^4+t_2^4+t_3^4)$$

$$=6(t_1^2+t_2^2+t_3^2)+(t_1+t_2+t_3)$$

$$=6((t_1+t_2+t_3)^2-2(t_1t_2+t_2t_3+t_3t_1))$$

$$=-12\cdot-\dfrac68=?$$

**See also** :  [Newton–Girard formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities)